# Can't disable validation of email in devise-auth-token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise-auth-token and want to sign in with field another than email.
So I used phone_number instead and everything is working properly but I  can't remove validation on email, here are my codes

user.rb

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, authentication_keys: [:phone_number]

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  validates :first_name,  presence: true,format: {with: /[[:word:]]/}
  validates :last_name ,  presence: true,format: {with: /[[:word:]]/}
  validates :email     ,  format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }, uniqueness: true
  validates :phone_number, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validate  :birthdate_in_the_future_invalid
  validates :country_code, presence: true
  validates :birthdate, presence: true
  validates :gender, presence: true
  # validates :file, presence: true
  validates :phone_number, phone: { possible: true, types: [:mobile], country_specifier: -> phone { phone.country_code.try(:upcase) } }
  validate :e164_phone_number


  after_create :set_provider_uid

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end

  def password_required?
    super if confirmed?
  end

  def password_match(password, password_confirmation)
    self.errors[:password] << "can't be blank" if password.blank?
    self.errors[:password_confirmation] << "can't be blank" if password_confirmation.blank?
    self.errors[:password_confirmation] << "does not match password" if password != password_confirmation
    password == password_confirmation && !password.blank?
  end

  private
  def birthdate_in_the_future_invalid
    begin
      if Date.strptime(birthdate, '%d-%m-%Y') > Date.today
        errors.add(:birthdate, "in_the_future")
      end
    rescue
      errors.add(:birthdate, "invalid format")
    end
  end

  def e164_phone_number
    if phone_number[0] != '+'
      errors.add(:phone_number, "invalid format")
    end
  end

  def set_provider_uid
   self.update_column(:uid, phone_number)
   self.update_column(:provider, "phone_number")
  end


end
```

and this is my initializers/devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  config.mailer_sender = 'aliabdelrahmanweka74@gmail.com'
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.authentication_keys = [:phone_number]
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:phone_number]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:phone_number]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11
  config.reconfirmable = false
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
  config.password_length = 6..128
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

I used funciton email_required? and make it return false but nothing happens

I call localhost:3000/users , Method Post
params:

```
{
    "user": {
        "first_name": "ali",
        "last_name": "weka",
        "gender": "male",
        "birthdate": "25-06-2016",
        "email": "",
        "phone_number": "+201118574649",
        "country_code": "EG",
        "uid": "+201118574649",
        "provider": "phone_number"
    }
}
```

and here's  the response

```
{"status":"error","data":{"id":null,"first_name":"ali","last_name":"ali","country_code":"EG","phone_number":"+201119574649","gender":"male","birthdate":"25-06-2016","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"provider":"email","uid":"+201119574649","avatar":{"url":null},"email":""},"errors":{"email":["can't be blank","is invalid"],"full_messages":["Email can't be blank","Email is invalid"]}}
```

so any help, please?

Comment: Hey please check the [link](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb) it's hardcoded email params you must override registrations_controller controller.

Comment: thank you, I override create function and replaced every email with phone_number but it didn't solve the problem, I need to provide a valid email so as to be able to get a success

Comment: Okay  just check migration file also it's set not null constraints for email

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I wanted some users with email, and some without.

### Solution

You should first remove the null: false restriction from users table with a migration. Should you want to remove the default "", do it to. Don't remove the index, so it still validates that emails are unique (in case you still use emails sometimes). Null values won't have a problem with the unique constraint.

If you are using devise validatable, add this method in your User model:

```
def email_required?
  false
end
```

After doing the previous part, you should do one of the following:

**Option 1**:
Going deep into devise_token_auth gem, at least in my case, I realized that [this concern](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/0c369d6338a362c1e888378b46e8251d8e5de947/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/user_omniauth_callbacks.rb#L3) was being included.

It's included by default unless you modify the DeviseTokenAuth initializer with

```
config.default_callbacks = false
```

But maybe you don't want that.

**Option 2**:
If you check the code in the concern I linked, you can see that it validates email in case the *provider* of the *user* is 'email'.

The fix in my case was to change the *provider* field to something else for the users that didn't have email.
With any of those 2 changes, your email won't be validated anymore.

---

For somebody who needs email sometimes:

- Of course, do what [Devise wiki says](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)
- apart from the other field include email in case_insensitive_keys, strip_whitespace_keys

and you can have a method in the User model with:

```
def email_required?
  true unless phone_number?
end
```